# Facebook iOS Application Cannot Log In On Device

Tags: ios, facebook

This is a very frustrating issue.  The DemoApp project from the iOS SDK from Facebook works just fine on the simulator but when I put it on the device it won't get past the log in page.  The only changes made to the code were:

1) Replaced the appID in the view controller
2) Replaced the appID in the Info plist

The application compiles and opens on the device.  The login button switches to a Facebook titled window with a Cancel button in the upper right corner.  The window has a large blue Log In button at the bottom. Clicking on the Log In button redirects to the same window.  This is the only Facebook iOS app on the device.  I deleted the others.  Also, the fbDidNotLogin() method is never called.  There have been several other posts about this issue but the solutions didn't seem to work in this case.  Is this enough information to see what is happening?  Do I need to build the application for a different target?  This is very confusing.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you just use ShareKit. If you are doing basic stuff with posting stuff to Facebook, why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: I want to access the Graph API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!  In Facebook.m is the following line of code:

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
```

The iOS SDK will try to use the Facebook application on the device.  Setting authorizeWithFBAppAuth to NO will launch Safari and that works.

Comment: weird but it helped. Now will try to get authorization through the app. Did you manage to get it? Facebook Hackbook Example app does authorize through FB app when I try it but for my app it was always a reject

Comment: Well. My problem was a very simple & stupid but hard to find :) I misspelled iOS Bundle ID in Facebook App Basic setting.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Replaced the appID in the view controller 2) Replaced the appID in
>   the Info plist

You should set "iOS Bundle ID" in application settings too. this is checked before authorization.

hope this helps

Comment: That didn't seem to help.  I edited my original post and put a screenshot of the authorization screen in the device.  Clicking the Log In button refreshes that window and nothing is different.  The handleOpenURL method is never called.

Comment: hm, I dont see any screenshot

Comment: It wouldn't let me post it because I haven't made 10 posts yet.  I found the answer.  Posted below.  Thanks for helping out!